# PHP Magic Method for assignment operator

Tags: php, types, variable-assignment, magic-methods

I'm trying to create a class that enforces its type much like the [PHP SplString class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splstring.php).
In this class you can create a string (example from php.net)

```
$string = new SplString("Testing");

try {
    $string = array();
} catch (UnexpectedValueException $uve) {
    echo $uve->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

var_dump($string);
echo $string; // Outputs "Testing"
```

I know PHP is loosely typed however they have got this functionality in SplTypes so I was hoping there might be some way of mimicking this behavior.

I would be expecting to implement it in this kind of fashion below.

```
public function __assign($value)
{
   if($value instanceof MyClass)
   {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

I'd like to be able to introduce this behavior in my own classes, but cant find the relevant magic method for assignments.

Is this even possible? Or is this a language feature that can't be controlled?

Comment: Magic methods only work when you assign or work with object properties. But an assignment like `$string = array();` completely severes the object association, overwriting the variable name with a new object (array). This has has nothing to do with dynamic/loose typing.

Comment: Im fully expecting this to be at the `c` level of php and not implementation. I don't believe it is possible.  It would be good to see a RFC in the near future to handle it though. The PHP parser could check for a  __assign method before any assignment, although its likely that it would slow down each computation.

Comment: There is no such magic method; SPLType fixation is handled at the C code level http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/spl_types/trunk/spl_type.c?revision=331721&view=markup and lines 216/217

Comment: Thanks Mark. that answers that I suppose :)